# How to make static container for referring a mutable instance from callback passed to C code?

Tags: rust, thread-safety, ffi

For the library I need to write I have a struct representing a service written in C:

```rust
struct RustService {
    id: u8, /* it's me setting the id in the first place */
    service: *mut c_void,
    status: *mut c_void,
    value: Option<u32>,
    /* various fields here */
}

impl RustService {
    fn new() -> /* can be wrapped*/RustService {
       /* ... */
    }
}
```

I have several callbacks passed to C library like this:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
extern "C" fn callback_handle(service: *mut c_void, size: *mut u32, buffer: *mut u8)
{
    let id: u8 = c_library_get_id(service);
    let instance: &mut RustService = /* get that from static container based on id */

    if size = mem::size_of::<u32>() as u32 {
        let value = buffer.cast::<u32>().read();
        instance.value = Some(value);
    } else {
        panic!("Invalid length passed.");
    }
}
```

What am I looking for is a proven/good practice that would apply here that works without causing deadlock, where my callback could refer back to the right instance using the library in C. That library in C can run multiple instances, however it's not that important. Alternatively I can accept a single instance pattern, that would work in this case.

Other methods of `RustService` would need to call for example a function with the following signature (from bindgen):

```rust
extern "C" pub fn clibCoreWork(status: *mut clibStatus, service: *mut clibService) -> u32;
```

and guts of that function may decide to call these callbacks mentioned above.

The approach I've taken shoots me in the foot as the **inner Mutex deadlocks** even in the single thread:

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref MY_INSTANCES: Mutex<HashMap<u8, Weak<Mutex<RustService>>>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}
```

I dug the internet but fellow Rustaceans didn't seem to post anything about such problem.

**Note:** I cannot change underlying types in the C library I'm using. In the ideal world it would let me store pointer to user data and I'd brutally convert it to a mutable reference in unsafe code.

Comment: When you are using `MY_INSTANCES`, am I correct in assuming your `RustService::new()` returns `Rc<Mutex<Self>>`? Also, is there a reason why the Mutex must contain the whole `RustService`? If possible it should be moved to wrap only `RustService.value`.

Comment: If you are that tightly integrated with as c lib, making a sound interface is hard, to say at least. Am I correct to assume your inner Mutex same-thread deadlocks? Have you tried using a reentrant Mutex (e. g. [here](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/0.11.0/parking_lot/type.ReentrantMutex.html)) instead? That won't hand out mutable references though, but I guess that is your smallest concern.

Comment: @tim-lundqvist More precisely `Arc<Mutex<<Self>>` - I tried `Rc`, but I couldn't compile. I would need several variables each with `Mutex` in such case, if there is no other option I'll do it, but... @l-riemer Mutability is my concern actually. I've looked into `parking_lot`. Now I'm thinking about something unsafe, but I don't know how far I can go with static.